# passig data between activities xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

I've looked around for tips on this, but I haven't found anything that helps...

Here is my code from the sending activity(VelgHemmeligTall):

```
                button.Click += delegate {  
                var hT = Convert.ToInt16(userInputNumber.Text);

                Intent newMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
                newMainActivity.PutExtra ("MyData", hT);
                StartActivity(newMainActivity);

                StartActivity (typeof (MainActivity)); };
```

On the receiving activity called MainActivity(stupid name for a second page, I know :P);

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "No data";


button.Click += delegate {
            Label.Text = "" + Convert.ToInt16 (anotherNumber.Text) + " and " + text; };
```

(This Label was made just to test if I got the data over to the next page...)
For some reason I always get "No data"... I've looked so many places, but haven't foud the sulution yet :/ Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Care to comment what you've tried other than I looked so many places? Different code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

It should work for you if you remove this line:

```
StartActivity (typeof (MainActivity)); };
```